# End to end testing - delete or keep records

Tags: testing, jestjs, end-to-end

What is the best way to handle records in the database after end-to-end tests have passed? Should we change affected records `deleted_at` column to the current date or remove these records at all since new tests will create more new records all the time?

The system will ignore those records with `deleted_at` flag but at the same time every new test will add new records and it will be equal for trashing database.

What is the best practice to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually start a docker container with a clean database or an initial setup every time we run the tests.
You can also clean the database in a beforeAll() function.
There is no need to persist the records created by the tests since you can add them
again

Comment: I thought the same. The idea is to run those tests not only in the local environment but stating also. But as you said, I've started using `beforeAll` method to wipe created records after all.